# How to I set the box for newly captured Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have organized my boxes in Pokémon X by type, and I have a few empty boxes at the beginning.

Whenever I capture a Pokémon, it does not go in the first Box available. How do I set the box that the Pokémon go in to?

Here is my setup:

```
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [X] [X] [X]
[X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X]
[X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X]
[X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X] [X]
```

The Xs represent boxes that are organized. I would like the Pokémon to go into the empty boxes at the beginning. Instead, they are currently going in to the 3rd to last box.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Was that a necessary edit? I'd consider that a minor edit =/

Comment: @Jerry I improved the suggested one, I guess they don't merge.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Still, I think it should have been rejected for being too minor first. Now looking through the review, I can see that someone else did reject on the basis of being too minor. Anyway, no sense in arguing that now that it's done, I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: @Jerry rollback or take it to meta. There's no point arguing it in comments *after* it's been approved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The box your capture Pokemon goes is determined as follows:

- Goes to the currently active box if it is not full.
- Goes to next box if current box is full.
- If next box is full too, goes to the next (applicable to any other subsequent full box).

Where an 'active box' is defined as the last box you see when you log off your PC.

If you want the Pokemon you catch to be in the first box, you will have to go to that first box and log off your PC to make that box the active one.

Comment: Oh, it goes to the next box now?  AWESOME.  I've stopped playing the newer games obviously.  Nothing like throwing a ball at a legendary and being told the box is full >.<

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, those were the old times when you even had to save and lose a lot of time to just change boxes, not forgetting that you could only withdraw or deposit. The 'move' feature is the one I always use now!

Answer (score 8):

Newly captured Pokemon will go in the box you were looking at when you last accessed the PC, or the nearest box to the right of that that has space if it is full.

For example, if you quit the PC looking at the full Box 14, and Box 15 is also full, the pokemon will appear in Box 16. This wraps back around to the first box if all the remaining boxes are full.

Just make sure you switch back to the first empty box after you're done messing around in your PC.